# Aberrant function behavior of PL/SQL procedure DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5

Tags: sql, plsql, md5, obfuscation, toad

I use TOAD for executing my procedures and running my PL/SQL scripts.

Recently, I tried the **dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5()** function in PL/SQL to retrieve encrypted text of the string I pass as a parameter. I found that, the function gives the proper result when I call the function as a separate statement. However, when I call it via a **SELECT** query, it does not respond the same format.

Below, I have mentioned this peculiar case with the results that appear once I run it in TOAD application.

```
--CASE:1 (Proper result is obtained here)
DECLARE
vinput  varchar2(255) := 'SRINI';
well    varchar2(50);
BEGIN
    WELL := DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(input_string =>VINPUT);
    dbms_output.put_line(well);
END;
```

**Output: Áýg¿Zq!Ù´¿Ke>ÏQ**

```
--CASE:2 (Unexpected response is obtained here)
DECLARE
vinput  varchar2(255) := 'SRINI';
well    varchar2(50);
BEGIN
    SELECT DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(VINPUT)
        INTO    WELL
    FROM    DUAL;    
    dbms_output.put_line(well);
END;
```

**Error Output:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 37:
PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'MD5' match this call
ORA-06550: line 5, column 12:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT"."MD5": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored**

Why is there such a disparity in the results, even though both of them are syntactically and semantically correct ? Please provide your opinion and feedback.

Comment: Err ... Your second example is not correct as can be concluded from the error message.

Comment: Sorry for writing it that way, still on a learning curve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function calls are not identical, syntactically nor semantically. If you call the function in PL/SQL as you did in SQL, you will get the same exact error:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     vinput VARCHAR2(255) := 'SRINI';
  3     well   VARCHAR2(50);
  4  BEGIN
  5     WELL := DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(vinput);
  6     dbms_output.put_line(well);
  7  END;
  8  /

ORA-06550: Ligne 5, colonne 12 :
PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'MD5' match this call
```

This is because the function called `MD5` is [overloaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) in the package [`DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_obtool.htm#ARPLS67278) and you need to specify which function exactly to call.

In Oracle 11g, you can use the same synthax as PL/SQL:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     vinput VARCHAR2(255) := 'SRINI';
  3     well   VARCHAR2(50);
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(input_string => VINPUT)
  6       INTO WELL FROM DUAL;
  7     dbms_output.put_line(well);
  8  END;
  9  /

Áýg¿Zq!Ù´¿Ke>ÏQ

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Before 11g, you can define a wrapper function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wrap_md5(input_string VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.varchar2_checksum
  3  IS
  4  BEGIN
  5     RETURN dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(input_string => input_string);
  6  END;
  7  /

Function created

SQL> DECLARE
  2     vinput VARCHAR2(255) := 'SRINI';
  3     well   VARCHAR2(50);
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT wrap_md5(VINPUT)
  6       INTO WELL FROM DUAL;
  7     dbms_output.put_line(well);
  8  END;
  9  /

Áýg¿Zq!Ù´¿Ke>ÏQ

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: Thank you @vincent Malgrat , you indeed cleared the doubt I had.

Answer (score 0):

select dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(input_string => 'SRINI') from dual; use this in select for the such type of function uses input string.